# What should be the Target SDK when publishing an Android app?

Tags: android, google-play, target-sdk

I have been working on an Android project from past one year in Eclipse with API level set to 4.2 (target SDK 17).
Now I want to publish it in the Play Store. Should I change the target SDK (manifest file) to the latest (i.e. 4.4) since my app works perfectly on KitKat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `targetSdkVersion` is explained [in the developer documentation for <uses-sdk>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html):

> This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).
>
> As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect.

TL;DR: You should set `targetSdkVersion` to the API level that you've primarily been developing and testing on. Google recommends that you see to it that this is the latest Android version, but that may not always be feasible (for financial and other reasons).

Answer (score 1):

See **your app will work fine with `kitkat`** because the newer versions are always made to be compatible with the older `android` versions,but vice versa is not true....if you develop something in higher `API` level  and then try to run it in older versions of android, than it may happen that your app may not work or some features may not work as expected.So,you too can add `KITKAT` compatibility in your android manifest file ...cheers

Comment: Well i checked in older versions too. but my question is should targetSDK(manisfest file) should be always latest during publishing time.

Comment: targetSDK should always be the latest. Beware, there are a couple of signature changes in some API levels that cause ambiguity so doublecheck your app when doing it.

Comment: mentioning latest API level will enable the users using **kitkat** to install your app as they can see your app in the playstore compatible with their devices....so i think its a good choice..  :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) you have to make sure to use a recent target SDK (at most one or two versions older than the most recent), otherwise you cannot publish your app in the Play Store. This is enforced for new apps as of August 2018 and November 2018 for updating existing apps, requiring you to target API level 26 or newer.